# How do I organize components in Aurelia.js

Tags: aurelia

How do we organize our components in Aurelia? It looks like in the default configuration, it looks at what's set in the "paths" in config.js.

```
paths: {
    "*": "*",
    "github:*": "jspm_packages/github/*",
    "npm:*": "jspm_packages/npm/*"
},
```

But I want to customize it and create multiple subfodlers (grouping the components). How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Just place those subfolders under the src folder and you're good to go.

```
src/
   comp-one/
      comp-one.html
      comp-one.js
   comp-two/
      comp-two.html
      comp-two.js
   app.js
```

Comment: This causes a funny import statement: from 'comp-one/comp-one" in typescript, this is minor, but what's the benefit of making the folders?